# How to avoid setting manual UIView width and height on native side for Fabric component when using CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, react-native, objective-c++, react-native-turbomodule, react-native-fabric

I am trying to create a `fabric` module for `iOS` using `react-native's` new architecture

In my `objective-c++` file while setting a `UIView`, I have to assign a `CGRect` at time of `init` of `UIView`. If I don't on the `native` side and just give it on `js` side the `view` is not visible.

Following does not work

```
Objective-C++

_view = [[UIView alloc] init];
_gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
_gradient.frame = _view.bounds;
    _gradient.startPoint = CGPointZero;
    _gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
 _gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    [_view.layer insertSublayer:_gradient atIndex:0];
self.contentView = _view;

JS

 <YourEdgeLinearGradientView
          style={{height: 200, width: 200, margin: 20}}
/>
```

Following works

```
Objective-C++ 

_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)];
...
...

JS

 <YourEdgeLinearGradientView
          style={{height: 200, width: 200, margin: 20}}
/>
```

but the issue is it occupies the width and height set on the `native` side and ignores `js` side
I want to use

```
_view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

without setting width and height on `native` side but setting it on `js` side

To add on more to this if I take a `UIButton` or a `UILAbel` instead of `CAGradientLayer` and apply `constraints` to `UIView` then I don't have to set `CGRectMake` to `UIView`

Also I don't want to pass `width` and `height` from the `specs` file, whatever I set from the style property should be applied. It works fine for `android` component but not for `iOS`.

I am currently using

```
view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

which causes issue and is not visible on `JS` side

If I use like below

```
_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
```

then it works but I don't want to set width and height on iOS side. I want to use `view = [[UIView alloc] init];` and whatever width and height I define in `styles` on `react-native side`, the `view` should occupy that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to your custom `CAGradientLayer` layer that has the same `frame` from its parent view, such as: zero frame by default - `[[UIView alloc] init]` or provided one - `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)]`.

```objectivec
...
_gradient.frame = _view.bounds;
...
```

And this layer's `frame` is not changed automatically when the view is resized so that you observe this behaviour and to fix this you should update the frame with `(void)updateLayoutMetrics:oldLayoutMetrics:` method of `RCTComponentViewProtocol`:

```objectivec
- (void)updateLayoutMetrics:(facebook::react::LayoutMetrics const &)layoutMetrics oldLayoutMetrics:(facebook::react::LayoutMetrics const &)oldLayoutMetrics {
  [super updateLayoutMetrics:layoutMetrics oldLayoutMetrics:oldLayoutMetrics];
  
  _gradient.frame = _view.bounds;
}
```